# Find with HABTM in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I know there are a bunch of these questions on SO and I've been through most of them but since I can't figure out where I'm going wrong I think I might be a nit-picky typo somewhere that I'm missing. Here are my models:

```
class Country extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Country';

    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Entity' => array(
            'className' => 'Entity',
            'joinTable' => 'countries_entities',
            'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'entity_id',
            'unique' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'deleteQuery' => '',
            'insertQuery' => ''
        )
    );

}

class Entity extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Entity';

    var $hasMany = array(
        'Alert' => array(
            'className' => 'Alert',
            'foreignKey' => 'entity_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );


    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'EntityGroup' => array(
            'className' => 'EntityGroup',
            'joinTable' => 'entities_entity_groups',
            'foreignKey' => 'entity_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'entity_group_id',
            'unique' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'deleteQuery' => '',
            'insertQuery' => ''
        ),
        'Country' => array(
            'className' => 'Country',
            'joinTable' => 'countries_entities',
            'foreignKey' => 'entity_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'country_id',
            'unique' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'deleteQuery' => '',
            'insertQuery' => ''
        )
    );

}
```

I want to do a find that returns all of the entities based off of a country id, i.e.

```
select entities.ticker from entities
join countries_entities on entities.id=countries_entities.entity_id
where country_id=78
```

Here's the latest iteration of the find statement I tried:

```
$blap = $this->Entity->find('all', array('recursive'=>1,'fields'=> 'Entity.ticker','conditions'=>array('Country.id'=>78)));
```

And this is the sql that Cake generates which generates a sql error (it doesn't try to build the query with the join table):

```
SELECT `Entity`.`ticker`, `Entity`.`id` FROM `entities` AS `Entity` WHERE `Country`.`id` = 78 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `$hasAndBelongsToMany` relations, it is often easier to call the `find()` on the model you want to filter itself:

```
$this->Entity->Country->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Country.id' => 78)));
```

It will return only the Country you want, and its associated models, which is basically what you want.

In this case, I'm not completely sure the `fields` param works on the associated model (Entity here), but if it doesn't, you can use the Containable behavior in Country instead.

Comment: This gets me closer. The contain is working the way I want but I'll open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

change the Association Type of EntityGroup hasMany in place of hasAndBelongsToMany in the Entity model class

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Entity->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('CountriesEntities')));

$blap = $this->Entity->find('all', array(
                                    'conditions' => array('CountriesEntities.country_id' => 78),
                                    'recursive' => 2
));
```